# Would like a recommendation for a good geometry text

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

So I am in the 8th grade and I have completed algebra 1. Next year, I will be taking geometry and algebra 2. I would like any good book recommendations that teach geometry. Something that is perfect for beginners, but is still quite challenging and thorough.

Thanks!

Comment: euclid's elements

Comment: I do not know any books in English, but DO NOT try to use Euclid's Elements to learn geometry. It is not a textbook. You will find nothing but discouragement. Save it for another time when you are more experienced.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin i thought the same... i was hoping for an intro before diving into euclids.

Answer (score 1):

Last year, i was fully obsessed with the book "Eulcidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads" by Evan Chen.

For olympiad aspirants, its truly one of the best books you can find. And yes, you can find a free pdf, and for that you need to email me at snakeisback12@gmail.com

It starts from the very basics, and increases its level and also contain lots exercises, which shoukd be good for one olympiad aspirant. So i highly recommed this book.

Personally, this book induced in me a 'temporary' love for geometry :D

Comment: i have this book. but this book is not suitable for beginners.

Comment: Thats your perspective. I dont think so its not suitable for beginners. Its completely okay.

Comment: this has no basic theorems

Comment: I see a lot of people disagree with you. Any way, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend any of these, approximately in decreasing order of difficulty (though they're all for beginners):

- *A School Geometry* by Forder. 
  Highly instructive problems. The level of rigor and difficulty increases considerably as the book goes on.
- *Basic Geometry* by Birkhoff and Beatley.
  An axiomatic approach, but with a simplified axiom system that allows you to get to harder (i.e., less intuitively obvious) material faster than in other treatments.
- *Geometry* by Lang and Murrow.
  The first author was a mathematician and a prolific textbook writer. The focus is on familiarizing the reader with geometric facts much more than on the deductive system, introducing proofs gently. Uses coordinates wherever this simplifies the treatment.