# How do I go about self-studying Maths? Do I create a routine? Answer a bunch of Q's?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, motivation

Im 19F & I'm starting my Computer Science course this year.
Before starting it, I wanted to make sure I had good GCSE & A level Maths knowledge.

The problem is I don't know how to go about self-studying Maths.
Do I answer textbook questions section per section?
Do I watch videos?
How do I know when I'm comfortable enough with a topic to move on to the next?
Do I do 1 section a day? How do I organise it all?

To add: I have plenty of time in my day to dedicate to self-studying. I have no commitments.
Apart from Maths, I'm also learning Java which is going well!

Please be kind, I'm new here :)

Comment: Do exercises. If you can't solve them, go a step backwards and try again. Concerning new definitions, there are usually only a few ones, try to make an example for it and a counterexample (Example: An integer $p$ is called prime, if $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ for all integers $a,b$. Example: $p=7$. Counterexample: $p=6$, because $6\mid 2\cdot 3$, but neither $6\mid 2$ nor $6\mid 3$).

Comment: If you have an A-level textbook, doing questions from that is perfect! You can also try to sit some past papers to assess your general areas of weakness, although a pretty vast portion of A-level isn't really applicable to CS, IMO (eg calculus). It also depends a bit on which exact course you're doing. If your course is quite theoretical, you should be sure to give a little more attention to "proofs". If you've done it, proof by induction is great to know about. Most of all don't worry too much about it, your course will likely refresh you on important concepts naturally.

Comment: Consider also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754499) question, its comments and answer

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes I have a textbook I am working through :) My course isn't too theoretical, BUT I want to learn math anyway because I also enjoy doing it in my spare time AND I enjoy doing Physics - which has a lot of Maths.

Comment: Hi, I'm unfortunately voting to close as this site is more for actual math questions (ie math problems), and this sort of question tends not to have "correct" answers so it attracts a lot of opinion-based answers. In the meantime, I would personally recommend just working your way through textbooks cover-to-cover, doing at least some of the exercises. If you find a book boring, try looking for a better-written one. You can also try this site's chatroom if you'd like to ask more "chatty" open-ended questions like this one.

Comment: @JackM Oh. My apologies. I already saw some of these questions on this site (soft Q's) but they didn't answer my questions hence why I posted my own. I am looking for different opinions though? From people who have a better understanding of Math than I do... Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do not try to exactly plan every step of the way. Grab some great books. Start with one of them. If it works then great. Go on with it. If not then change it. If you plan all the steps just now, in the future when you have become a different person (a more mature one), you will realize that lots of the steps should change based on your new perspective and needs. So don't waste your time on them just yet. Grab a book. Study it carefully and do as many exercises as you can. :$)$

Answer (score 4):

Each one learns differently, find a method that works for you.

Narrow down, "mathematics" is *huge*. For Computer Science, you'd need some logic/proof techniques (check out some texts/lecture notes on "bridge" courses, I happen to like Hammack's ["Book of Proof"](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof)). Combinatorics, some graph theory are a must. Perhaps go for Sedgewick's ["Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms"](https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home), it has very polished slides/videos. I'd also look e.g. at Erickson's ["Algorithms"](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms). Not mathematics per se, but much of the material on algorithms is applied mathematics, it will at least give you an idea where it much of it is going. Also to consider is Lehman, Leighton and Meyer's ["Mathematics for Computer Science"](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring18/mcs.pdf)(look around, there might be a newer version available). Note that the cited texts are *not* easy, perhaps you'd need some more introductory material to get started.

I'd also take a peek at Downey's ["Think Python"](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e) (make sure you get the second edition, the first one concentrated on --now discontinued-- Python 2), it will teach you much about what computer science/programming is all about.

Check out syllabi of schools that interest you, perhaps the lecture notes or texts cited are a better bet for material, or give you an idea what they deem important to start out. Or make a good complement to the above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply & for the links! My course itself isn't too theoretical, BUT I want to learn math anyway because I also enjoy doing it in my spare time AND I enjoy doing Physics - which has a lot of Maths. Which is why I asked this Q. How best to learn Maths from GCSE - undergrad level? Do I just answer textbook Q's and watch videos, is there any other method that works much better?

Comment: @Miia, what works best for you doesn't need to be the one that works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, I guess it helps to be more specific about your goals and tasks. Students tend to wander around with their thoughts, being romantic about the idea of studying any subject and thinking about how they ideally could study.

But the simple truth is: You have to work on what you have to work on. And your goal probably will simply be "Understand every detail of the course." Eventually "learning and understanding math" will take care of its own.

A lot of this work includes work, that appears as "unnecessary" or "uncomfortable" for the student. But this work is actually crucial to learn for a student. For example, contacting your lecturer, asking questions about details and willing to work on details for a longer period of time. Also willing to ask a second time about the detail you have not understood, when he/she explained it the first time.

If you think about it twice, you will realise, that the best way to prepare for your course, would be to find out, who your lecturer is and what this course is about in more detail. A lot of professors taught the same course some time ago and have scripts and textbooks available on their homepage for this specific course. Find out about that and study this textbook. If you cannot find this textbook, ask yourself again, what obvious task has to be done otherwise and how you can solve it. Probably: Ask your lecturer, if he has already a script for the course or a textbook, he can recommend. And **actually write** this mail. Tasks that feel uncomfortable to be done, sometimes can have the most impact on solving an issue. This does not mean that you should not use any other books. It only means you should use books in order to understand the topics and contents of the course.

Otherwise this can lead to a typical frustation a lot of math students experience: They will try to work around the "uncomfortable tasks" by spending a lot of time on "somehow understand", but will have an even harder time studying for the **actual course**. They spend too much time on trying to learn from books or thinking about how things should be, instead of facing and attack the next step, they should be actually working on. Courses are designed to teach you the steps that are necessary to be done. Instead of thinking about, if the course is done right way, you should rather try to think about, how you can deal with it the right way.

And lately about studying a math text for a course. It is again quite simple. Read it from beginning to the end. If there appear details, you do not understand: Spend time to make a good request for that, for example here on stackexchange: Write down the problem properly, write down what you already have tried to solve the problem, write down your question properly. Often, just by figuring out, what you want to ask, you might find an answer to your question yourself, because you specify about what you want to find out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You're right :) Also, since I'm not just learning Maths for my course ( I enjoy doing Maths in my spare time as well as physics - which has Maths) is there any other advice you have for me? How do I know when to move on from a topic? How long do I spend on 1 topic? Right now I feel really stupid answering these basic questions I seem to have forgotten how to do:/

Comment: Also, In terms of Goals like you mentioned, I guess my goal right now is to be knowledgable on GCSE Math at least, and the aim is to have started A level Math before uni - because both are needed. I've wasted so much time already, and I don't want to waste more - hence why I was wondering what the best & most effective ways to learn Maths are? Thank you :)

Comment: Well, I have to admit, the most effective way for me was to cancel my internet connection contract, haha. But seriously, pick only one book, which prepares you for A level. Try to read it from the first to the last page, carefully. If there is a detail you do not understand, try to locate the actual step or equality sign you are wondering about. Try to solve it yourself first and write down your ideas. If you can't solve it, write down a question properly and post it as a question here on stackexchange. You have to let people know, what you are working on and what you are trying to understand.

Comment: You should never spend so much time on a problem, that you feel frustrated about thinking on it. That's why it is good to ask question early on and learn how to ask questions here on stackexchange. You can learn how to write LaTeX just by looking at other posts which look nice. Simply click the "edit" button of a post and you will see how it is written. To find about the LaTeX symbols itself, you can draw them here: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 2):

*I'm copying the comments I posted under your question, so that they are more cohesive and easier to read.*

I'm doing Computer Science too (starting 2nd year). I think every person should develop their own, unique way of studying, because all people are different, and you can't really create a perfect solution for all of them. Personally, I usually find the topic I want to learn, then search forums etc. for the best books on that topic, and pick one them. Then I go through of all of the theory and make sure I understand it, and only then I proceed to solve some exercises related to that topic.

As for the organisation, it depends on my mood. Sometimes I can go for hours without getting tired, but sometimes I give up doing almost no work. I think it's pointless to force yourself to do fixed amount of work every day, because to learn maths you need the right mood. Without it you might do hours of work with little to no effect, so it's more efficient to wait for the good disposition. It all depends on the type of topic you learn too. You should consider diffrent approaches if the topic is more theoretical or if it's more practical.

Another advice I can give you, that I think is very useful is to make breaks, especially when learning theoretical topic. You can walk away from your desk, do some coffee or sth and in the meantime try to sort the infomations you have learnt and put them in order, and generally think about them, their uses, connections to other topics you already know etc. I think doing this is very important to thoroughly understand topic, and I usually do such breaks every 30min when learning theory and every hour when doing exercises. Such breaks allow me to remember and understand the topic way faster.

Also, many people agree that teaching a topic is the best way to learn it as well. While you obviously may not have someone to teach if you are learning alone, but you can imagine that you are teaching someone given topic, and think of ways you could present it to him/her. I usually do that during these "breaks" I mentioned above, and I find this method really helpful.

*If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.*