# Is Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang rigorous?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Does *[Basic Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387967877)* give a suitably rigorous treatment of algebra and geometry topics covered in high school? Does it prepare the reader for more difficult texts like *Calculus* by Spivak? I also found the trigonometry chapter to be too brief so, Is there a need for a supplemental book for trigonometry with *Basic Mathematics*?

Background-
I am 13 years old and recently became interested in pure mathematics. I have completed *[Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817636773)*
by Gelfand. I was looking for a rigorous textbook that covers high school mathematics when I came across this book.

Comment: The term "rigorous" has two reasonable meanings in your question, one which has to do with the intellectual challenges of the mathematical content and the other has to do with the logical precision and accuracy of the mathematical content. Which of these meanings are you asking about?

Comment: I agree with Dave Renfro, but since both interpretations are clearly relevant in your situation, I'll answer for both. With respect to logical precision, the answer is that Lang is good but not perfect. He generally does a good job of honestly identifying for the reader those points where he is not being fully rigorous. These points are almost always ones where he reasonably feels full rigor isn't desirable considering his readership. For example, he doesn't rigorously define real numbers or the operations on them, but he does state explicitly what he assumes about them. He doesn't...

Comment: prove the existence of $n$th roots, but he states explicitly what he does assume. There are some points where I would disagree with the choices he makes. For example, having accepted the existence of $n$th roots, he could have been fully rigorous in deducing the possibility of defining powers to rational exponents. Instead, he assumes that it is possible to do this in such a way that the exponent laws will work.  He also never sets out what the "basic properties" of area are that he assumes as known. But these are minor quibbles. On the whole, Lang compares well to most books at a...

Comment: comparable level. If you don't want to wait for calculus to dot all the $i$'s and cross all the $t$'s, you could read *The Real Number System* by Olmsted in parallel. On the question of whether Lang will prepare you adequately for Spivak, the answer is maybe. It's better than most books for this, because it does devote considerable attention to proofs. On the other hand, it doesn't develop a high level of computational skill in important areas. That's why in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731176/rigorous-and-comprehensive-textbooks-on-precalculus/3731894#3731894)...

Comment: I recommended supplementary reading. The strongest students will be able to make a transition directly from Lang to Spivak. But I think many more will find they can follow the arguments in Spivak but are less successful at carrying them out themselves. The experience of reading Spivak will be less satisfying for them because they will be able to solve a smaller proportion of the problems than they otherwise would. The single most important aspect of this is skill with inequalities, and that's why one of the books I recommended was *An Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach and Bellman...

Comment: With all of this being said, if you're eager to start with Spivak, there's no problem in just starting and seeing how successful you are on the exercises in the first few chapters. I'm not writing this as an answer because I don't want to discourage other people from giving their own views, considering you've heard mine before.

Comment: In US high school 1955, plain Euclidean geometry that was taught consisted of axioms, theorems, proofs and constructions.   Has education deteriorated from that quality?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Have you actually looked at the quality of American geometry textbooks of that era (or any era)? The insistence on two-column proofs has done a lot to inculcate in American students the harmful belief that form is more important than content when it comes to proofs. Schoenfeld makes this point eloquently in his paper ["When good teaching leads to bad results: The disasters of "well-taught" mathematics courses."](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/TiMER/Schoenfeld%20(1988)%20Good%20Teach%20Bad%20Results-2.pdf)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro considering that these two qualities do not necessarily conflict with each other, can't a rigorous book have both these qualities?

Comment: @Anonymous I am actually eager to start with Spivak. But I don't want to go ahead and learn higher mathematics without properly learning the basics. You gave me some good suggestions for books to supplement *Basic Mathematics*. I'll look into them.

Comment: Please answer the questions as an answer and not as a comment so people can access it easily :)

Comment: @Anonymous  I read most every page of one geometry book.  Yes, I'm appalled at the restricted and over demanding  requirements of logic proofs.  What caused that new fad of floor and ceiling equations?  Is there a point to it?   Modular intergers has become monsterized by turning the modulus relation into a binary operator.  Is that and that oxymoron partial function the curse of computerists' bumbling comprehension of mathematics?

Comment: *... do not necessarily conflict with each other ...* --- Sure, and I did not intend otherwise. I suppose I should have said something like "Which one and/or the other of these two meanings ...".

Comment: It might not be perfectly rigorous, by the standards of a real analysis textbook, but Basic Mathematics is a very good book and I definitely recommend reading it. But since you said you're eager to start with Spivak, I say go ahead and dive into Spivak. (You don't have to commit to reading books one at a time, in a linear way. If you find gaps in your knowledge, you can just backtrack and look at other books to fill in the gaps. If you find that you're not getting much out of one book, you can try another book.)

Answer (score 8):

If rigor means "logical precision," the answer is that Lang is good but not perfect. He generally does a good job of honestly identifying for the reader those points where he is not being fully rigorous. These points are almost always ones where he reasonably feels full rigor isn't desirable, in view of his readership. For example, he doesn't rigorously define real numbers or the operations on them, but he does state explicitly what he assumes about them. He doesn't prove the existence of $n$th roots, but he states explicitly that he assumes this without proof.

There are some points where I would disagree with the choices he makes. For example, having accepted the existence of $n$th roots, he could have been fully rigorous in deducing the possibility of defining powers to rational exponents. Instead, he assumes that it is possible to do this in such a way that the exponent laws will work. He also never sets out what the "basic properties" of area are that he assumes as known.

But these are minor quibbles. On the whole, Lang compares well to most books at a similar level. If you don't want to wait for calculus to dot all the i's and cross all the t's, you could read *The Real Number System* by Olmsted in parallel.

On the question of whether Lang will prepare you adequately for Spivak, the answer is maybe. It's better than most books for this, because it does devote considerable attention to proofs. On the other hand, it doesn't develop a high level of computational skill in important areas. That's one reason why in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731176/rigorous-and-comprehensive-textbooks-on-precalculus/3731894#3731894)
I recommended supplementary reading. (The other reasons are to build general mathematical maturity and that the additional reading I suggested is, I feel, interesting in its own right.) The strongest students will be able to make a transition directly from Lang to Spivak. But I think many more will find they can follow the arguments in Spivak but are less successful at carrying them out themselves. The experience of reading Spivak will be less satisfying for them because they will be able to solve a smaller proportion of the problems than they otherwise would. The single most important aspect of this (after typical courses in high school algebra) is skill with inequalities, and that's why one of the books I recommended was *An Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach and Bellman. An alternative would be a similar book by Korovkin.

With all of this being said, if you're eager to start with Spivak, there's no problem in just starting and seeing how successful you are on the exercises in the first few chapters.

Reading Spivak ought to clear up most of the concerns you may have about rigor in high school mathematics (in the sense of logical precision), but I will add a few more comments about this.

If you're *exceptionally* concerned about rigor, you can get the full story on the set-theoretical foundations of mathematics from a book like *Introduction to Set Theory*, by Jech and Hrbacek. This builds up from the axioms of set theory to a construction of the natural numbers, and later of the integers, rational numbers and real numbers. The problem is that while such a program is pre-Spivak in purely logical terms, it is post-Spivak in the demands it places on readers' mathematical maturity. For comparison, Spivak constructs the real numbers in the last part of his book, but he takes the rational numbers and their properties as intuitively known. My opinion is that few people would benefit from working through a set theory book before Spivak, but it may be helpful to have a general idea of what the steps are in providing a firm logical foundation for mathematics.

Even then, one might say that full rigor hasn't been achieved until one has presented a way to formalize the concept of proof to such an extent that the correctness of any given proof can be verified by an algorithm. (Such formal proofs are almost unreadable to humans because they are full of symbols.) This is accomplished in books on logic.

Edit: I forgot to answer the part about trigonometry. Plane trigonometry can be divided roughly into two parts: (1) geometric applications to triangles, quadrilaterals, etc.; (2) analytic trigonometry, which involves various algebraic manipulations of trigonometric functions. For the more advanced aspects of (1), good knowledge of (2) is necessary.

Part (2) is important, and I agree that Lang's book is short on this topic. But the trigonometry and complex number chapters of Parsonson's *Pure Mathematics 1* and *2* (which I mentioned to you previously) ought to be quite enough for this. It's not necessary that this be taken beyond the level of Lang before you study calculus.

I think part (1), apart from the straightforward cases of solving triangles, is optional and is certainly not a prerequisite for calculus. A reasonable approach, supplementing what is done in Lang and Parsonson, would be to read some of the more geometric chapters of Parts II and III of Durell's *Elementary Trigonometry* and the initial chapters of his *Advanced Trigonometry*. (You'll be able to determine for yourself what is or isn't duplication for you when and if you study these books.) These can be downloaded [here.](http://knowledge-dojo.com) For the later chapters especially, good knowledge of plane geometry is likely to be helpful. Kiselev (which you mentioned elsewhere that you're reading) is enough for this. An alternative could be (approximately) Chapters 10-12 of the book by Hobson, which you mentioned you're also reading.

Comment: Does Hobson cover all the topics that the two books by Durell cover? What are the topics where Hobson falls short?

Comment: I'll assume you're only talking about the geometric aspects, because as I said, I think Parsonson is enough on the analytical aspects. The truth is, I don't know Hobson's book well enough to give a detailed answer to your question. What I can say is that Hobson looks broadly comparable to Durell on this. When I answered your first question, I mentioned Durell's first book mainly thinking it would be used before moving on to the level of Spivak, Parsonson, etc. In that context, I thought Durell was preferable to Hobson because it doesn't deal with the more analytic aspects (such as infinite...

Comment: series expansions) that I think are best left to the calculus stage. Judged purely on geometric content, I don't have any reason to think Hobson would be less good than Durell. I don't recommend the parts of Hobson or Durell's second book that deal with infinite series and complex numbers, because I would prefer to learn these in more modern books (on calculus and complex numbers).

Comment: You mentioned a book, *Algebra, and Analysis of Elementary Functions* In the comments of the answer you linked to in your answer to this question. Do you prefer that book to *Basic Mathematics*?

Comment: Since you asked this question, I've had a much closer look at the book by Potapov, which I know less well than the books I've recommended. It had originally seemed to me to be a good deal more rigorous than Lang, and therefore I thought it might be close to what you wanted. It does contain a good deal more material than Lang, and it proves some things that Lang doesn't. But there are some omissions where I feel a warning would have been appropriate, but wasn't present. For example, in defining addition of rational numbers, the book fails to point out that we must check that in a sum of two...

Comment: rational numbers, if each term is replaced with an equivalent fraction, then the sum is replaced with an equivalent fraction. I feel this is worse than what Lang typically does. So if there are points where you wonder how to make certain things on algebra in Lang more rigorous, I'd feel more comfortable recommending Olmsted as an auxiliary reference. There are more difficult exercises in Potapov than in Lang, but again, there are better alternatives, such as the problem books by Krechmar and Lidsky.

Comment: What do you think about [this one](https://libgen.lc/ads.php?md5=6EA711AC0C11734ED4A8BF90CB546733)? Too advanced?

Comment: That one isn't a textbook to learn basic mathematics from. I've looked at it before, though mainly the volume on geometry. It's a presentation of various issues in elementary mathematics from an advanced standpoint. It would be unusable for you until you were already generally at university level.