# Good multivariable calculus textbooks for non-math vs math majors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here's a question. I work as a TA for multivariable calculus course this semester, and one of the student asked me about a good and helpful reference for the topic. We are using Stewart's book as an official material, and I've heard that Thomas' one is another good reference. However, since it's been almost 10 years ago that I learned multivariable calculus before (and actually I didn't take any course on it because I didn't have to for some reason), so I wonder if there are some other good books that you can recommend. I actually know a book named "Calculus 2" written by Hongjong Kim, which is a really great book for math majors but not for non-math majors. (It refers de Rham cohomology at the end of the book). So here are my questions:

1. (Important) Good book/materials on multivariable calculus for non-math majors
2. (Less important) Good book/materials on multivariable calculus for math majors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were 1. and 2. supposed to be different?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I hope so, but I know that they could be the same.

Comment: I think Thomas means that one of 1 and 2 has a typo. At present, both ask for materials for non-math majors.

Comment: The first one asks for "Good book/materials on multivariable calculus for non-math majors," and the second one asks for the same.

Comment: @ThomasAndrewsn Ohhh I'm so sorry, yes it was a typo. I edited.

Comment: Depending on the level and ability of the students, Lang's book might be worth considering. See my comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4517007/13130).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for your recommendation. It looks good for me. I'll recommend this to the students.